# How to standardize error handling from API requests across a ReactJS application

Tags: reactjs, axios

In my React app, I am trying to figure out how best to create a function (or hook) that will process errors returned by our API when a request fails. I am finding that the `catch((error) => {})` method from my `axios` calls are becoming verbose and repetitive in order to handle all error scenarios and to display those errors to the end user for each request. I can see how this could be a recipe for disaster if the API slightly changes the resulting error payload, it would require a change in many parts of the application.

There are generally three types of errors that our API returns: 1) a "general" error generated by the API, 2) a validation error which identifies specific fields (i.e. patch request), 3) an "axios error" for things like timeout, bad request, internal server error, etc.

Is there a framework or library that already handles this type of issue? I am a bit new to React so perhaps I'm missing something obvious.

Below is a code snippet of a typical "form submit" example, but we also have many other instances where there is no form and we just have a simple patch/update request - all of which need this type of error handling.

```
// Valid values for "requestStatus"
const REQUEST_STATUS = {
    REQUESTING: 'requesting',
    INPUT: 'input',
    ERROR: 'error',
    SUCCESS: 'success',
}

// Submits the form data
const onSubmit = async(formData) => {

    if (requestStatus===REQUEST_STATUS.REQUESTING) return;
    // Set a requesting status so we can show a "spinner" in the UI
    setRequestStatus(REQUEST_STATUS.REQUESTING);
    // Reset the error message
    setGeneralRequestError(null);

    // Submit the request
    axios
        .patch('end_point_data')

        .then((response) => {
            // Set to success
            setRequestStatus(REQUEST_STATUS.SUCCESS);
            // Update the UI using reducer
            emailIntegrationContext.dispatch({type: ACTIONS.UPDATE, id: appUserConnect.appUserConnectId, payload: response.data.payload});
        })

        .catch((error) => {

            // Is this an error generated by the API?
            if (error.response?.data?.error) {

                // Change status so we know to display errors in the UI
                setRequestStatus(REQUEST_STATUS.INPUT);

                // Get error payload
                const errorPayload = error.response.data.error;
                // Used to parse into general errors / field errors
                const errorMessages = [];
                const fieldErrors = [];

                // Are there any general errors in the payload?
                if (errorPayload.messages != null) {
                    errorMessages.push(errorPayload.messages);
                }

                // Are their any validation errors in the payload?
                if (errorPayload.validationErrors) {
                    errorPayload.validationErrors.map((validationError) => {
                        if (validationError.fieldName) {
                            fieldErrors.push(validationError);
                        } else {
                            errorMessages.push(validationError.message);
                        }
                    } )
                }

                // Set so we can display the general errors
                setGeneralRequestError(errorMessages)

                // Parse the field validation errors to display in the form
                fieldErrors.map((fieldError) => {
                    // Use custom method to change some field names so they match the form input names
                    const fieldNameTransformed = fieldNameTransformer(fieldError.fieldName);
                    // Set field errors in React-Hook-Forms "setError" method 
                    setError(fieldNameTransformed, {
                        type: 'server',
                        message: fieldError.message
                    })
                })

            // Must be bad because axios generated the error
            } else {
                setRequestStatus(REQUEST_STATUS.ERROR);
                setGeneralRequestError(error);
            }
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: "Is there a framework or library that already handles this type of issue?" the React ecosystem is massive, the answer to this question is usually yes, I can recommend [reactQuery](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/queries) (powerful) or [SWR](https://swr.vercel.app/) (easier)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've used ReactQuery (albeit briefly), but I'm pretty sure it doesn't have tools to handle the situation I'm describing.  It handles queries (and error handling from those queries), but what I'm looking for isn't that.